# jwplayer ignoring auto-play when set to false and then showing MEDIA12899 error

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, video, jwplayer

I have 3 videos on a page that should load but with the auto-play function set to false, as follows:

`function loadStartUp() {
        registerVideo('VIDEO1', false, 'mediaplayerRestaurant');
        registerVideo('VIDEO2, false, 'mediaplayerbus');
        registerVideo('VIDEO3', false, 'mediaplayerShop');
}`

where `registerVideo` is as follows:

`function registerVideo(vid, autoplay, playerId)`

The auto-play function works for firefox and chrome, but automatically plays the 3 videos simultaneously when opened in IE(11)

IE(11) also throws an MEDIA12899 error (AUDIO/VIDEO: Unknown MIME type) when trying to load the next video. - No errors in other browsers.

Comment: On further inspection the mime type is frequently not sent, but the few times that it decides to send it sends an octet-stream type. How would I change this to an mp4 mime?

Comment: adding `<staticContent> <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" /> </staticContent>` to Web.config doesn't work

Comment: Do you have a link you can provide?

Comment: It's currently being developed on a local server, so I don't have a link unfortunately.

Comment: Mime issue sorted when used on demo server, yet all three videos still simultaneously play when the page is loaded. (Still an IE only issue)

Comment: At this point you need to provide a link. Please put one up so this can be debugged properly.